# How can I find cells with conditional highlights?

Tags: excel, formatting, find, highlight, conditional-formatting

I've used a formula to highlight certain cells yellow. However, when I go into **Find and Replace** and select a yellow fill from **Format**, Excel doesn't find anything. The **Find what** field is blank when I search.

I think that Excel doesn't view these cells as filled with a colour, as the preview has no fill when I use **Choose Format From Cell** on a highlighted cell.

Comment: I found **[this solution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/highlight-patterns-and-trends-with-conditional-formatting-in-excel-for-mac-c3130a89-7ebf-41ac-ab93-e8f58bb42844)** at the top of Google's search results when I copy/pasted in the title of your question. If that doesn't solve your issue, check out how to create a [mcve] to include in your question (to show what you've tried). Also helpful is "[ask]".

Comment: Why not use the Conditional Formatting dialog - there you see all ranges that have a formatting

Comment: If your question is not about programming, perhaps it is better suited for https://superuser.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/find-all-the-cells-having-conditional-formatting-in-google-sheets/